# Why local classes in Java can`t have static methods?

Tags: java

In method main is class Counter that have method quantity that returns quantiny of numbers in given String.

```
 public static void main(String... args) {

    class Counter{
        static final String numbers="0123456789";
        int quantity(String main){
           int i=0;
            for (char c:main.toCharArray()){
                if (numbers.contains(Character.toString(c)))
                i++;
                }
         return i;
        }
    }

    String str="a0b3s2d6";
    Counter c=new Counter();
    System.out.println(c.quantity(str));
}
```

I think that creating instance of Counter is uselles, calling just `Counter.quantity(str)` will be easier than creating instance. So Why we can't have static methods in local classes?

Comment: What if one wants to override method, well you can not override static method and hence you loose inheritance OOPS concept

Comment: You could refactor your `Counter` class outside of the `static void main(...)` method and declare the the Counter class as well as the method static. This should enable you to call `System.out.println(Counter.quanitity(str));` from within the main method if this is acceptable for you

Comment: @AnantLaxmikantBobde Utility classes are often designed in that way. Either adding a new method to the utitlity class or creating a new utility class here are often the solution. If a utility class is explicitely designed with flexibility in mind, than a strategy pattern could be used to switch the concrete implementation at runtime - Spring Security `SecurityContextHolder` class is build on that concept f.e in that you can define its strategy as either `GLOBAL`, `THREADLOCAL` or `INHERITEDTHREADLOCAL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local classes can be only created when the parent class is initialized. Mentioning them static means that they should be created before the class initialization which wouldn't be possible.

For more details , see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html)

Answer (score 1):

Static :  static keyword to create fields and methods that belong to the class, rather than to an instance of the class.We make members and methods static so that it can be used elsewhere and called from anywhere by using class names but

If we will make members of inner class static still we wont be able to access it outside that class.

In this case an inner class is associated with an instance of its outer class, it cannot define any static methods itself. A static nested class cannot refer directly to instance variables or methods defined in its enclosing class, it can use them only through an object reference.

Answer (score 0):

Because static methods could be called from anywhere of your code.

How would you call static method of the class `Counter` that you could not reach because it is in the local scope of some other class?

You're doing something wrong.

**UPD**

Why you trying to instantiate your static class?

`Counter c=new Counter();`

What goal are you actually trying to reach?

Comment: That one is not a static class. That one is a [local class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html).

Comment: When you are declaring static members, you're implicitly declaring static class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want call the method like `Counter.quantity(str)`,You can define the class out the main method.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String str = "a0b3s2d6";
    System.out.println(Counter.quantity(str));
}

static class Counter {
    static final String numbers = "0123456789";

    static int quantity(String main) {
        int i = 0;
        for (char c : main.toCharArray()) {
            if (numbers.contains(Character.toString(c)))
                i++;
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```